# check duplicate row in html table

Tags: html, node.js

I am using Node js and mysql. I am trying to check if an entry in mysql database table exists in the html table. If the entry doesnt exist it should be added otherwise it shouldn't be added. However, there is something wrong in the code and i cant find what it is. I want to check if the id in the last cell in the row is equal to the id of the record in the mysql table. However every time i press the tab it is adding duplicate records. Can someone please help. Thank you

Here is the code for the function:

```
function addRow(tableID) {
        // find the number of rows in the table myreservations

        <% for(var i = 0;i<reservations.length;i++) { %>

            var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
            var rowCount = table.rows.length;
            var foundalready = false;
            var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

            for(var i=0; i<rowCount;i++){

                if(<%- JSON.stringify(reservations[i].rid)%> == table.rows[i].cells[6].id){

                    foundalready = true;
                    break;

                }
            }

            if (foundalready == false){    
                var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
                var element1 = document.createElement("input");
                element1.type = "checkbox";
                element1.name = "chkbox[]";
                cell1.appendChild(element1);

                var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
                cell2.innerHTML = rowCount;

                var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
                var element2 = document.createElement("div");
                element2.type = "text";
                element2.textContent=<%- JSON.stringify(reservations[i].tablenumber); %>;
                element2.name = "txtbox[]";
                cell3.appendChild(element2);

                var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
                var element3 = document.createElement("div");
                element3.type = "text";
                element3.textContent=<%- JSON.stringify(reservations[i].stime); %>;
                element3.name = "txtbox[]";
                cell4.appendChild(element3);

                var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
                var element4 = document.createElement("div");
                element4.type = "text";
                element4.textContent=<%- JSON.stringify(reservations[i].etime); %>;
                element4.name = "txtbox[]";
                cell5.appendChild(element4);

                var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
                var element5 = document.createElement("div");
                element5.type = "text";
                element5.textContent=<%- JSON.stringify(reservations[i].priority); %>;
                element5.name = "txtbox[]";
                cell6.appendChild(element5);

                var cell7 = row.insertCell(6);
                var element6 = document.createElement("div");
                element6.type = "div";
                element6.id=<%- JSON.stringify(reservations[i].rid); %>;
                element6.name = "txtbox[]";
                element6.textContent = <%- JSON.stringify(reservations[i].rid); %>;
                cell7.appendChild(element6);
            }
                <% } %>

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont really get the whole code, but things are that there are things that you can't be doing. 
1- in the two loops you are using the same increment variable i. 
2- you are doing  `var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);` and further in the if clause you are doing

```
if(<%- JSON.stringify(reservations[i].rid)%> == table.rows[i].cells[6].id)
```

look, this conditions can never be satisfied. you need to recheck the objects you are considering and all the stuff around.

Comment: When i changed the variable i in the second loop i got a reference error. Also i didnt get what's wrong with the if statement. Can you please explain to me whats wrong with it? Thank you